# "di quattro in quattro"

Tags: word-meaning, meaning

I'm trying to understand the following phrase from a text of the seventeenth century:

> Immediatemente seguiranno doi monaci con le Cotte, et Torcie accese et appresso quattro coppie de Monaci Cucallati senza Lume et in ogni interstitio di quattro in quattro seguono li doi Monaci con la Cotta et torcie Accese

It's describing a procession, but I'm not sure what 'di quattro in quattro' means. Could somebody explain, either in Italian or English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would translate that roughly as "every four by four".

> Immediately two Monks will follow with the Cotte and torches lit and afterwards four couples of Monks Cucallati without Lights (or candles or torches, maybe) and in the place every four by four (couples of Cucallati) the two monks with the Cotta and the torches lit.

Basically, the procession is, as far as I understand, as follow: 2 monks with torches, 4 couples of monks without torches, 2 monks with torches, 4 couples without, etc...